# Is there a bug on tag search?

Tags: support, tags

I searched questions tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), and I obtained the following results (look at first question):

[image: c++ tag seardh results]

Refreshing the page a little bit later left the question out of results, so it looks like a race condition issue.

Comment: I just don't understand the downvote. Had this question been asked before I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @PaddedCell is entirely correct; we cache that data pretty aggressively - there are some minor oddities that can occur if the cache is not quite up to date, but they are *so* short-lived that it is genuinely not worth the impact of treble-checking the results shown (which might then involve loading different data to compensate for differences with pages of data etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No repro on my end.

Buuuuuuuut it might be a simple caching issue (I mean, if it is an issue at all), [the question was tagged with c++](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7580460/revisions).

Answer (score 2):

There is always a lag when the tags on a question are edited before the new tags are reflected in searches. This is easy to test yourself and I see it all the time when retagging.

Not a bug, just caching.

**Edit:** I just removed [python](/questions/tagged/python) from a question, and it showed up in the search results for *maybe* three minutes before disappearing.